# Displaying a custom message when selecting an item from the list-box

Tags: vb.net

Suppose I made a list of two names (Furqan, Hanif). When I select the first name and click on the button, I want a message to pop up which says something, e.g. "Gone For Fishing". When I select the second name and press the button again it should show me a different message, e.g. "Sleeping". How can I made this program in Visual Basic?

Comment: Its very easy to get the selected item of listbox on button's click. So just go for it.

Comment: @TheGuy, please be sure to read the tag descriptions when performing retagging.  The original tagging was bad, but your replacement tags were *worse*.  This is not an IDE question, this is a VB.net question.

Comment: @Charles Yeah, sorry. The question came up in the first posts review queue, and I didn't want to skip it (the last few times I've skipped reviewing, the next person clicked `no action needed`). I saw that `visual-studio-2010` was an IDE, and the tag was for questions related to "this particular version of Visual Studio". Because I had no experience in this area, I didn't know if the `visual-studio` tag was necessary, so I kept it (thinking that the author would know better than me). I saw that the language was "Visual Basic", so I added that tag, not knowing the correct one was "vb.net".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something to get you started...there are **many** ways to go about this:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If ListBox1.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
            Select Case ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString
                Case "Furqan"
                    MessageBox.Show("Gone For Fishing")

                Case "Hanif"
                    MessageBox.Show("Sleeping")

                Case Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Unknown Person")

            End Select
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Select a Person First!")
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Will You Please Elaborate This "ListBox1.SelectedIndex <> -1" what is to do with -1???

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx) and look at the message in that last `Else` block.  I think you'll be able to figure it out...